# wicket: changes does not appear after page reload

Tags: java, eclipse, wicket

I have created java Project with wicket in eclipse. the application works fine. The problem is, when I change the java code in the project and reload the page to see these changes, the changes do not appear.

The changes appear only when I run the project again (right mouse click on the project -> run as -> java application). Is there a way to see the changes after reloading the page without needing to run the project again every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use debug-as instead. This will instruct eclipse to use hotswap and update your running application. Note that you'll still need to restart your application often since hotswap doesn't support all class file changes. For that you'll probably need to use a class-reloading solution, such as JRebel, or use the redeploy feature of a container.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Wicket >= 1.5? You might also be stumbling over the page version parameter that Wicket appends to every URL of a stateful page, e.g. `?5`

If you simply reload the page with this parameter, the page will be rendered again, but not constructed new from the scratch, which might also lead to your changes being ignored.

It's quite annoying, but to get a proper reload of the page, you need to remove the parameter and hit enter.